Approach for characterizing 'shape' of plotted time-series data
I have a collection of time-series data aggregated at 1 second intervals over several days.
I'm attempting to formalize different 'regimes' that may exist/appear via shape of the plotted data.  For instance whether a V shape, T shape or A shape is more frequent and at which times of day, hour, minute, etc.  Have included a few examples of the plotted data below.
My first thought was to try something PCA-ish to reduce dimensionality of data in service of summarizing different curve shapes that tend to appear but results weren't terribly informative.
It's possible there's nothing meaningful here and I'm chasing my tail but wonder if other approaches exist for this kind of problem that I'm simply not aware of.




If there are a relatively small number of common shapes, then a dimensionality-reduction method like PCA ought to work well.  Could you, therefore, explain the sense in which that failed to be informative?

@whuber, couple things:  (1) I don't expect there are a small number of common shapes (ie, plenty of noise); (2) looking at explained variance, even through 5th component, was only seeing ~50% of total variance explained, with top couple components individually in the teens.

"Small number of common shapes" and "plenty of noise" are completely different things!  Taking "plenty of noise" at face value, it's still the case that with hundreds of thousands of data points (that's the implication of readings every second for several days) and assuming the series were detrended, differenced, cleaned, and perhaps standardized (you did all that, right?) it would be extraordinary that five PCs account for 50% of the variance.

@whuber, appreciate your thoughts.  All data was standardized and is generally stationary, yeah.  I guess devil's advocate then, what is really the point of reducing dimensions in a situation like this if even reducing from 10 to 5 dimensions doesn't well-describe behavior in a meaningfully simpler model?

Isn't your question about exactly that?  The mathematical translation of "a few regimes" is "low dimensional approximation."  If there's no point, then I don't get why you're asking this question in the first place.

@whuber, I guess by 'no point' I mean, 'how much better is a model with 5 variables than one with 10?'

For that kind of question to be answerable, you need to describe how to measure "better" in a way that (in principle, at least) can be quantified.
